# Нет знака "Эрудит" в списке в профиле

Tags: дефект, статус-так-задумано, знаки, профиль-участника

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/15/generalist

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Там много знаков нет, например "Гуру", знаки по очередям проверок, "Учёный муж" и другие....

Comment: На MSE был пост про то, что отображаются только знаки, по которым прогресс считать не слишком  накладно.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ как ответ оформите )

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, я вот [прошу на MSE модераторов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/324003/wildcard-tags-unrolling-issue#comment1058971_324003) так не делать, а у нас, получается, то же самое. При установке красных меток хорошо бы давать поясняющий ответ или хотя бы комментарий, иначе не очень понятна причина такой «задумки».

Comment: @αλεχολυτ так вы ведь в комментариях написали.

Comment: @Suvitruf я могу ошибаться, особенно без явных ссылок на первоисточник.

Comment: @αλεχολυτ https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298790/260198

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, я правильно понимаю, что теперь всё ОК? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, вас выручили :)

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ух, пронесло)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб невольно вспомнился анекдот про Петьку и Василия Ивановича

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, который? =)

Comment: @ЮрийСПб когда их обоих пронесло

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нагуглил пока только [такой ответ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/298790/260198), подтверждающий слова @alexolut:

> The badges that are not trackable have mostly been selected as
>   non-trackable because **tracking them** (for each and every user) would
>   cause an overly **high load on our databases** and systems. A bunch of
>   badges are very expensive to calculate and calculating progress on
>   them is even more so.

Сделано намеренно, чтоб нагрузку снизить.

Comment: Мне казалось, я видел другой ответ. Но этот тоже вполне подходит :) кстати Generalist там в списке не приводится почему-то.